# How to import a python module inside lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda, python-import

For suppose depending upon the variable I want to import some classes, create its object and return it.
for example :

```
if x=='SomeThing':
  import something
  object = something's object
else:
  import nothing
  object = nothing's object
object.function()
```

I want to do the above using the lambda how can I do this?

Comment: You can't use an `import` statement inside a lambda expression.

Comment: Why do you want to use a `lambda`? Just use a standard function def

Comment: I want to decrease the size of code that is the only reason behind using lambda

Comment: That is the worst imaginable reason to use a lambda.

Comment: Still decreasing the size of code is one of the lambdas usage and i want this at different level.

Comment: No, lambda expressions are used when you don't otherwise need a name for the function being created. The "size of the code" has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rarely an issue to simply import *both* modules unconditionally, and select which module to actually *use* later.

```
import something
import nothing

(something if x == 'SomeThing' else nothing).object.function()
```

If you *do* need to perform conditional imports, import one or the other, but using the *same* name.

```
if x == 'SomeThing':
    import something as thingmodule
else:
    import nothing as thingmodule

thingmodule.object.function()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use magic [`__import__`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/__import__.html):

```
importer = lambda x: (__import__("pandas").DataFrame if x == 0 
                      else __import__('numpy').arange)
```

**NOTE**: This is extremely ugly, and not at all recommended, unless you absolutely need to do it.